# Throw compiler error if const value is wrong (static assert)

Tags: c++, static-assert

I made a class for an arduino program. Inside the class I would like to toss a compiler error if a wrong pin number is passed as an argument.

```
class AnalogOutput : public AnalogBlock
{
public:

    AnalogOutput( uint8_t _pin ) : pin( _pin )
    {        
        static_assert
        (       pin ==  3 
            ||  pin ==  5
            ||  pin ==  6
            ||  pin ==  9
            ||  pin == 10
            ||  pin == 11 , "INVALID PWM PIN USED" 
        ) ;
    }

    void run()
    {
        if( IN2 != prevIn )
        {   prevIn  = IN2 ;                // if incoming change, update PWM level

            analogWrite( pin, IN2) ;
        }
    }
  
private:
    const uint8_t pin ;
    uint8_t       prevIn ;
} ;
```

The constructor is only called with compile-time constants.

```
static ServoMotor M1 = ServoMotor( 3 ) ; // 3 is the pin number
```

Yet I get me this compiler error

```
error: non-constant condition for static assertion
         static_assert (
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: use of 'this' in a constant expression
```

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424661/generate-compile-time-error-if-compile-time-constant-parameter-is-wrong) but it did not make me wizer. It is the first time that I am trying to use `static_assert()`.

First question: what I am trying to do, can that be done in the first place?
Second question: providing that the previous answer is 'yes' how can it be done?

In responds to Erel's answer:
I tried this:

```
template<uint8_t pin>
class AnalogOutput : public AnalogBlock
{
public:

    AnalogOutput( uint8_t _pin ) : pin( _pin )
    {        
        static_assert
        ( 
                pin ==  3 
            ||  pin ==  5
            ||  pin ==  6
            ||  pin ==  9
            ||  pin == 10
            ||  pin == 11 , "INVALID PWM PIN USED" 
        ) ;
    }

    void run()
    {
        if( IN2 != prevIn )
        {   prevIn  = IN2 ;                // if incoming change, update PWM level

            analogWrite( pin, IN2) ;
        }
    }
  
private:
    const uint8_t pin ;
    uint8_t       prevIn ;
} ;
```

I construct an object

```
static  AnalogInput a1 =  AnalogInput(0) ;
```

And this give me this error

```
error: invalid use of template-name 'AnalogOutput' without an argument list
 static AnalogOutput a1 = AnalogOutput(0) ;
```

I also get several notes:

```
note: class template argument deduction is only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z

note: 'template<unsigned char pin> class AnalogOutput' declared here
 class AnalogOutput : public AnalogBlock
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I compile with avr-gcc

Comment: You could templatize only the constructor instead of the whole class.

Comment: You could use a class enum or another type as parameter instead, which ensures that the pin number is correct before calling the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

A way without using any templates, is to make a [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) function that only returns the constructed object if the condition is met. If the condition was false, it returns nothing and therefore the compiler will throw an error:

```
#include <cstdint>

struct ServoMotor {
    constexpr ServoMotor(uint8_t pin) {}
};

constexpr bool valid_pin(uint8_t pin) {
    return (pin == 3 || pin == 5 || pin == 6 ||
            pin == 9 || pin == 10 || pin == 11);
}
consteval auto make_motor(uint8_t pin) {
    if (valid_pin(pin)) {
        return ServoMotor(pin);
    }
}

int main() {
    auto m3 = make_motor(3);
    auto m4 = make_motor(4);
}
```

the line on `m3` works as expected, but there is an error `C7595` on the `m4` line, since 4 is not a valid pin.

---

Try it out [here](https://godbolt.org/z/rfWoEdcfa).

Answer (score 0):

`static_assert` is for compile-time constants only, thus, because you try to run something in the context of object construction (hence, runtime), the compiler refuses to generate code.

An alternative solution would be to use a `template`d `class` like such:

```cpp
template<uint8_t pin>
class AnalogOutput : public AnalogBlock
{
        AnalogOutput() : AnalogBlock(/*whatever goes in there*/){}

        static_assert
        (       pin ==  3 
            ||  pin ==  5
            ||  pin ==  6
            ||  pin ==  9
            ||  pin == 10
            ||  pin == 11 , "INVALID PWM PIN USED" 
        ) ;
    //blablabla
};
```

And instead of doing

```cpp
AnalogOutput o = AnalogOutput(pin_number);
```

You do

```
AnalogOutput<pin_number> o {/*Arguments for constructor go here*/};
```

**Though I remember having bad times with `template` in Arduino due to bugs in their compiler.** It was a few years ago, but still, use at your own risks.

Comment: I cannot get this to compile. Does it matter that my class is a subclass?

Comment: @bask185 I don't know, you did not post the error you got or a godbolt showing the code you tried.

Comment: @bask185 Okay, this is simple to fix. It's simply because you don't construct the object the same way as before. I edited my answer.

I also advise you use [https://godbolt.org/](https://godbolt.org/) for such situations instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking an `uint8_t`, take an auto and pass an `std::integral_constant<uint8_t, value>()`, where `value` is the value you'd like to pass (e.g. `3`). It can be checked compile-time and can be converted to the underlying integral type, i.e., `uint8_t`.